# Compress the silence - audio file formats

Tags: audio, mp3, compression, audacity

How do you compress audio silence?

I'm using Audacity and have been exporting variable compression mp3s.  But a 1minute audio track is about the same file size regardless of how much silence there is.

And it's complete silence (0% audio).

Is there another audio compression format I have to use, or a config option, I'm missing.  My audio tracks are 75% silent (because it's instructional audio), and I need to optimize them for the web.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, OGG might, but it [doesn't look well supported in Safari and IE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp).

Here are my results.

`Original`: audio clip of 34s of dialogue.
`Silenced`: audio clip of 34s with 20s silences (14s of dialogue).

- Avg compression @ 128bits: 490KB vs 497KB
- Standard preset: 567KB vs 527KB
- Variable compression (145-185kb): 472KB vs 436KB
- Ogg (5 quality): 398KB vs 176KB  <-- Success!!

Comment: I just tried doing this with Adobe Audition, and by making a bunch of the middle silent I could shrink a file from 11MB to 3.6MB.  So MP3 format should work.  It might be a problem in Audacity or the settings you have?

Comment: @AlanShutko, thanks for the heads up. I tried a variable of export options and posted my results above.  No luck, except for Ogg.  If you have any insights about your export options, let me know.  One thing I noticed is that my mp3 encoder doesn't allow a wider variable compression range than 40kb.

Comment: Are you using CBR or VBR (or even ABR)? If you use CBR, the size will not change regardless of the content, right? Have you tried VBR/ABR?

Comment: The problem is that "silence" probably isn't digital silence, it's low-amplitude white noise.  Most encoders are going to attempt to encode it and use much more space then necessary.  Pre-processing your audio to turn that into digital silence and using a VBR encoding should get an encoder to use the minimum possible space.

Comment: @afrazier, that's a good point.  When I did my test in Audition, I created the file by setting a range to all-bit-zero.

Comment: @afrazier, it's digital silence, insofar that it's programmatically inserted.  There's zero white noise.  And the problem with VBR, as far as I know is the bit rate range is limited to 40kbps.  I'm still at a loss as to how Alan got it working.  I need to get a copy of Audition I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'd posit you can get away with VBR (Variable bitrate) AND a lower overall bitrate specification.  I believe if you specify the same bitrate on 2 audio streams and one compresses better then the other, you would land up with better quality at the same size, so simply invert that logic.

Comment: I don't know how you'd get a VBR range larger than 40kbps.  There's just no range that would produce great audio and optimize for silence in that range.